# Change label's name using image button is not working

Tags: javascript, html

This code is supposed to change the name of the label when we click the image button.

This is not happening. One thing I observed when I look closely is: when the button is clicked, the label changes but it changes back to the original value immediately.

When I use a normal button the change is working.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function change(n)
            {
                var e=document.getElementById("name");
                e.innerHTML='jnbjkvnkx';
            }
        </script>
        <form>
            <label for="name" style="width: 300px; padding-left: 5cm" id="name">hemanth</label>
            <input type="image" src="page31.png" onclick="change('name')">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *when i use normal button the change is reflecting the button* - Does this mean you're not using a normal button in the actual code? If so, what type of button are you actually using?

Answer (score 2):

The label value doesn't get changed because once you click on the button, the page refreshes to a new page with x and y as the coordinates for the image type.

There are several ways to fix this issue:

1.) Use `input type = button` and using CSS change the background image of button.

2.) Use `<a href='#' onclick='change()'><img src='page31.png'></a>`